# C++ : What is the usage of int('0') in this code?

Tags: c++, function, int

This code Find the sum of all digits that occur in a string.

**Example**

> sumUpNumbers("2 apples, 12 oranges") = 5  //2+1+2

Can anyone explain the need for use int('0') in this code!?

```
int sumUpDigits(std::string inputString) {

  int answer = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < inputString.size(); i++) {  
    if ('1' <= inputString[i] && inputString[i] <= '9') {
      answer += int(inputString[i]) - int('0');
    }
  }

  return answer;
}
```

Comment: same as `(int)'0'` but with C++ syntax

Comment: to clarify, `int(X)` is redundant in this code.  The key point is `inputstring[i] - '0'`, which is covered by the duplicate; and there are redundant casts.  Whoever wrote this code didn't know the language very well.

Answer (score 1):

It converts char into ASCII code to make number out of string

```
int('9') - int('0') = 9
```

Comment: Why you used int('0') it has nonsense here since int('9') is 9

Comment: @user3289638 In my world `int('9')` is equal to 57

Comment: @user3289638 see `http://www.asciitable.com/`

Comment: Oh, it's clear now to me thanks a lot Severin